# How can I set the user running the service?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, connection-string

I created a MVC4 web application on my laptop using localdb with a mdf. file. I then exported the project to my desktop, and then I copypasted these files over to my webserver on my Win2k12 running IIS.

After copying it I created the tables on the MSSQL Express 2012 server that runs on the same Win2k12 server, and modified web.conf in my project to target the server and not the mdf file.

And here is where it all stops, I get the following error when I try to send data (that should communicate with the sql server, browsing pages is fine as long as it does not try to talk to the sql server):

Cannot open database "mc.foo.net" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\mc.foo.net'.

And I'm guessing the user IIS APPOOL is something inherited from my laptop, I don't have this user on thw Win2k12 server. How can I change that? And to what? I have several users (from Security of the server in SQL Server Manager):

- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
- NT SERVICE\SQLWriter
- NT SERVICE\Winmgmt

In addition to my domain administrators. How can I fix this?

Comment: IIS APPPOOL is a special "pplication pool identity", you can read more about it here: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the application pool identity in IIS Manager.
On the target application pool (under Root/application pools), select *Advanced Settings*. The is a Category *Process Model*, where you can specify pool's identity.

[image: pool]

Built-in account allow you to use Network Service/Local System/... whereas Custom allow you to specify a domain or local user. That's all !

It's not recommended to give too many privileges on the application pool. This can hurt security of your application and can be sometimes painful to manage. So, I would highly suggest you to use sql authentication for your database and to encrypt connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like the user doesn't have rights on the DB Server.

There are multiple ways to  go around this.

1. If you are connecting through integrated security to the DB... Change that to a local SQL server or a domain username and password.
2. Give your appPool account dataReader or dataWriter access (Not recommended for production).